# Second screen toolbars/launcher not working (15.04 fresh install)

Tags: unity, external-monitor, 15.04, launcher

I've just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04 on a Dell Latitude E6420 with an external monitor. Everything works fine on the external screen, but the launcher and toolbars do not react when clicked on the internal screen.